# CSS animation not working in Safari but fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, animation, safari, sass

I'm using SASS and here is the code I'm using

```
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }  
  @-ms-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }  
  @keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin transition() {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

@mixin animation($str) {
  -webkit-animation: #{$str};
  -moz-animation: #{$str};
  -ms-animation: #{$str};
  -o-animation: #{$str};
  animation: #{$str};      
}

@include keyframes(fadein) {
  from  { opacity: 0; }
  to    { opacity: 1; }
}

.fadein {
    @include transition;
    @include animation('0.5s ease-in-out .7s normal forwards 1 running fadein');
}
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't execute in Safari. 
I have tried with percentage values inside the keyframe like

```
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
```

but this didn't fix it either.

In the console in Safari appears an exclamation mark in the CSS animation line, here is a screenshot of it

[image]

What could the issue be?

Comment: what does the code for `transition` and `animation` look like?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I have edited the question.

Comment: I think the issue is with the parameter I'm passing to the @include animation(). In fact it is, it should look like this `fadein 1.5s ease-in-out 0s forwards`. I spent like an hour trying to figure this out and obviously I got it figured out after posting the question on SO!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my bad for not having checked the animation properties syntax before asking here. I thought I had it right..! It should be

```
@include animation('fadein .5s ease-in-out .7s forwards');
```